# Completion of Infopath form by 2 employees before it enters in a 2 step approval workflow

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, infopath

So here is the case, I am new to SharePoint and I am trying to create a 2 step approval workflow so two managers can approve or reject a request. The problem I am facing is that before the (InfoPath) form reaches the first approver I want it to pass by someone to complete the "cost" field that the user can not (the idea is for orders, someone wants to order something but someone else is responsible for completing the "Cost" field). Does anyone have an idea of which technique should I use or even provide me with links that can be useful to me?

I am using SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 0):

1. Use a Rule that allows only the designated user to be able to edit the cost field.  Have the workflow send the task to this user first.
2. Have the workflow in a "wait" state until the cost field has a value and send it on to the approver.  Something like "if costField <> "" Then send task to approver"

Are you using SP Designer or 3rd party like Nintex or K2?

Comment: Yes I have already used a rule for the user not to be able to edit the cost field. Forgot to mention that I am using sharepoint designer 2010. I have created a 2 step approval process but before these two step approvals I need the second person to fill out completely the form (fill out the "cost" field in my case). The problem is, with which action in SPD can I, first, send the form to the second person to fully complete the appropriate field and then start the approval processes?